# After a reboot and latest CU for sqlserver 2017 I get this annoying message

Tags: sql-server-2017, logs, cumulative-update

After a reboot and latest CU for sqlserver 2017 I get this annoying message (the xxxxx was a number)

> SSBDT: Dialog timer delete during registration (did:
> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:Initiator, OpType: CloseDialog
> OpResult: Null)

I've read that it isn't to worry : true?
This message is filling my sql server logs every second: how can I make it stop?

Comment: Did you look at [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/234595/sql-server-2012-service-broker-ssbdt-spam-ending-conversations-after-sending), [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/c7e80057-3191-4803-98c2-99d7444a4e67/sql-server-2016-error-ssbdt-dialog-timer-delete-during-registration-and-ssbdt-dialog-timer-delete?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade), [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/86b8a5c8-a882-496e-a4c4-99a5bbf2f935/ssbdt-dialog-timer-delete-during-dispatch-with-sql-server-2012-sp3?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade)? If you restart again, does it stop?

Comment: Do you have any of the mentioned trace flags enabled at the server level (1165, 3502, 3605)?

Comment: yes looked all an more , but no clue to stop it , the only thing that I am a little sure that is harmless , I have those trace enabled : TraceFlag
845
1204
1222
2371
2467
3605
7745
7752  so 3605 yes

Comment: thought disabling 3605  it is not a good solution to me

Comment: .. ok but I lose control on deadlocks

Comment: You're using 3605 for... deadlocks? Tell us about that please... and why you aren't using Extended Events for those (and why you still think you need 2371 enabled)...

Comment: Yes , but I can manage to do it with extended events , it' s more modern , in the meanwhile I disabled 3605 and now everything is fine , but I still don't know how this started, if you write your reply in the answers I will vote you , Merci beaucoup

Comment: and yes you're right trace 2371  isn't useful anymore